Разработка системы для идентификации одного и того же автомобиля на различных сайтах объявлений
У нас задача, в рамках которой необходимо определить, когда один и тот же автомобиль выставлен на продажу на различных платформах объявлений, таких как Mobile.de и AutoScout24. Основная сложность заключается в том, что VIN номер в объявлениях обычно не указывается, что делает прямое сравнение данных объявлений затруднительным.
Первоначально я рассматривал подход с использованием хешей изображений для сопоставления объявлений, но это может привести к ошибкам в случае, если изображения не являются уникальными или были взяты из общедоступных источников.
Вот несколько подходов, которые я рассматриваю:

Анализ метаданных и текстовых данных объявлений.
Использование алгоритмов компьютерного зрения для анализа изображений.
Разработка или применение нейронных сетей для сопоставления объединенных данных (текст, изображения, метаданные).

Мне интересно узнать ваше мнение о возможных решениях этой задачи или опыт работы с подобными проблемами. Какие подходы или технологии вы бы рекомендовали для реализации этой системы? Есть ли специфические инструменты или библиотеки, которые могли бы помочь в решении этой задачи?
Благодарю за любые советы или предложения!

Если человек не парясь будет ставить одинаковые фотки и описание, то достаточно сравнить фотки, описание - и даже никаких нейросетей не нужно. А если он сделает другие фотки и другое описание, то задача, мне кажется, вообще не решаемая. Или вопрос в том, чтобы найти объявления, которые тырят с одной платформы на другую чисто копипастой?

@CrazyElf задача собрать все данные, и убрать из них дубликаты, собрать нужно не только с тех твух сайтов, а есть еще пачка
